# Stuck in recovery mode, power button broken

Tags: recovery-mode, reboot, buttons, power-on

My Samsung galaxy j5 (2015) is stuck in recovery mode, If I pull and put back the battery it boots in recovery, if I let the battery run out and then charge again it still boots automatically in recovery mode.
No custom recovery, no custom rom, it is rooted, I can't remember if usb debugging was on.
On the bottom it says:

```
No Support SINGLE-SKU
Supported API: 3
dm-verity verification failed...
```

One day I accidentally restarted it on recovery because the power button is broken and I use an app to turn it off, it has remained like this since, it was fine before.
I tried using adb but I don't know why my pc can't see the device.
I really don't want to lose my data.
Can someone help me?

(Btw, why when I press a button the selected option becomes green?)

Comment: dm-verity verification failed means that the system partition was altered. This could be cause by malware or the flash memory is simply dying. If you could make the phone to enter download mode you could try to reflash the latest system firmware using a  connected PC and Samsung PC software. That is the only way I see to get access to your data.

Comment: @Robert that might be because I used an app to extend to system partition to sd, but that sd was removed a while ago and the phone kept working fine. I think I just need to find out how to reboot the phone normally. Would flashing the firmware get it out of recovery? Would I lose my data? Would it boot back to how I left it?